# How can you use multiple modules in a Raku project, if the modules are defined in the project?

Tags: raku, rakudo

I'm playing around with writing modules in Raku, when it made sense for me to break a piece of functionality off into another `.rakumod` file. How can I link these files together when I compile?

I tried to pull the other module to my main module via:

```
use MyProject::OtherModule;
```

But I get an error that it can't find this module even though they're side by side in the directory. I tried looking at some OSS projects in the Raku world, most of them are one file, the compiler Rakudo seems to use multiple module files but I can't figure out how they're linked.

Do I have to publish this module every time I want to run my project? How do I structure this if my project gets huge? Surely the best solution isn't to have it all in one file?

**Edit**: I should also note that I used this at the top of my new module too:

```
unit module MyProject::OtherModule;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When running locally, if you have your META6.json declared, you can use

```
raku -I. script.raku
```

and it will use the uninstalled versions, and you don't need to add any `use lib` in the script.

Comment: Maybe my question wasn't clear enough, I would like to use a `.rakumod` file within another `.rakumod` file that lives in the same directory.

Comment: In A.rakumod, add ‘use b’